# Accessing a class ivar from a C function

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a C function in a class (yes, has to be in C) and I need to access an ivar from that class. The ivar in question is a NSMutableDictionary.

From what I understand, C functions don't have direct access to ivars of a class and a reference must be passed to them. So, I have added this before the implementation

```
static NSMutableDictionary *myIvarRef;
```

and did this on the init of that class.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        myIvar = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        myIvarRef = myIvar;
    }
    return self;
}
```

later, inside that function, when I try to use myIvarRef it is nil.

What am I missing?

thanks

---

The C function is complex to put here, but the line that I am trying to use is like this

```
MyObject obj = myIvarRef[myKey];
```

I put a breakpoint at this line and when it stops I type `po myIvarRef` on console and it gives me nil.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you weren't missing a retain.

Comment: Can we see the c function, and how you R calling it...?

Comment: Do you create more that one instance of the class? Note that each `init` call overwrites `myIvarRef`, so that it always points to the ivar of the *last created* object. - You definitely should look for a different design. Perhaps you can pass a pointer to the object as an additional parameter to the C function.

Comment: @MartinR - that's it. I have without realizing, importing a class from another project that had the same name (old version of this class that was not updated) and this was causing the problem. Please add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the big problem that the static `myIvarRef` variable is overwritten in
each `init` call, and therefore always points to the ivar of the *last created* object.

A better solution would be to pass the object pointer as an additional argument to the
C function. Something like this:

```
void myFunction(void *uData, /* other parameters */ )
{
    MyClass *obj = (__bridge MyClass *)(uData);
    // Now you can access all properties, ivars etc of obj.   
    // ...
}

- (void)myMethod
{
    // Call C function from Objective-C method:
    myFunction((__bridge void *)(self), /* other arguments */ );
}
```